# Is it possible to adjust pixels per inch of a image imported as plane.?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image

I am trying to simulate a display screen in blender. For that I imported the image that I want to display as a plane in blender. But the dimension of all the images imported as plane are fixed as 1mx1m even though the images have difference sizes. I want to simulate the display having a common pixel per inch that way I will obtain the images size according to their pixel dimension. Is there a way to simulate so?

Is it possible to fix the pixel per inch of image imported as plane in blender?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry this first part because I am sure you know this, it is mostly for people who read this and might not know this: pixels per inch (ppi) is usually used for screen resolutions, how many pixels a monitor can show per inch. Many confuse this with dots per inch (dpi) and this is used for printing images, although in reality - especially in non-professional printing - images are mostly scaled to fit the size they are needed and not the size determined by the given dpi. Which means, if you have images of 1920×1080 pixels, they have these on-screen dimensions but can still be 72 dpi or 300 dpi. As I said, you might know it, just for other users reading this answer. This becomes important if you perhaps want to import images from different sources and they all have the same pixel dimensions, but if you scale them by their dpi you might end up with different sized image planes. This can be desired if the dpi setting is intentionally different, but can be irritating if you thought they should be the same size.

Anyway, have you tried the different options when you use the import *Images as Planes*? If you scroll down to the bottom there you will find *Plane dimensions:*

[image: plane dimension options]

- *Absolute* : there you can set the absolute *Height* of the image plane, 1 m is the default setting, *Orientation* > *Align* > *Face Camera* is optional and can be changed.

  [image: absolute height]
- *Camera Relative*: lets you change between *Fill* (the image plane is scaled so that its shortest dimension fits the longest of the camera window) or *Fit* (the longest dimension of the image plane fits the shortest of the camera window). With this option, the *Face Camera* alignment is mandatory and cannot be changed. While on all other options the resulting plane size can easily be calculated from the image dimensions, here the plane size is dependent on the camera settings and the camera position relative to the 3D cursor (where the plane is placed).

  [image: camera relative]
- *Dpi* and *Dots/BU* (dots per Blender unit): here you can define how many pixels of the image should equal (dpi) how many inches in real-life dimensions of the image plane or (dots/BU) how many Blender units of the image plane, with default Blender settings set to *Metric* this usually means pixels per meter. Alignment can be changed as well.

  [image: dots/inch and dots/BU]

Comment: Thank you for the reply and proper explanation of the terms. Dpi options resolved my issue.

Comment: @Vidya Yeah, I guess in this case dpi is the best option to convert from ppi